# Confounding ABC in factorial experiment

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, confounding, fractional-factorial

Consider a $ 2^3 $ factorial design lay out in 2 blocks ,each of size 4, as follows

Block I:  {1,a,b,c}

Block II: {ab,ac,bc,abc}

Here,the treatments combinations are written in  Yate's notation. Then which of the following are always true?

a)  Main effect  A is confounded

b)  Main effect  B is unconfounded

c)  Interreaction AB,BC,AC are all unconfounded

d)  Interreaction ABC  is confounded

***below I show my attempt***

considering the following expression while confounding ABC

(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)

the possible division is

Block 1:  (1 ,AB ,BC ,CA)

Block 2: (A , B , C , ABC )

There must be something wrong with the question or I am missing something ? Please suggest if I am wrong .

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. I too feel that there should be some discrepancy with the problem. Normally we ***avoid*** confounding main effects, as we don't want to lose information on them. The effect which is confounded has an **even** number of letters in common with **all** the elements of the **controlled block** (Here the block containing treatment combination $(1)$). You have already shown a possibility where **$\mbox{Int} ABC$**  has been confounded. Similarly, if we would like to confound **$\mbox{Int} AB$** then the treatment combinations are as follows:-

**Block I**: $(1),(ab), (c), (abc)$

**Block II** $(a),(b),(ac),(bc)$

Under the assignment given in the particular problem you could not confound any of the first and second order interactions.